# How to Match with OR condition in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have nodes of type User, Item, and Comment.  A User can LIKE an Item.  A User can POST a Comment, and a Comment can be POSTED_IN an Item.

I'm trying to find all Items that are either LIKED or Commented by a specific user (or both).  The query I'm using is:

```
MATCH (u:User {id: 'r1tcX0vxW'}) 
WHERE (u)-[:LIKES]->(i:Item) 
OR 
(comment:Comment)-[:POSTED_BY]->(u) AND (i:Item)<-[:POSTED_IN]-(comment)  
RETURN i;
```

However, this query has a syntax error.

I also thought about doing this via OPTIONAL MATCH, but I'm not sure how to accomplish that.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one

```
MATCH (u:User {id: 'r1tcX0vxW'})-[:LIKES]->(i:Item) 
RETURN i 
UNION 
MATCH (u)<-[:POSTED_BY]-(:Comment)-[:POSTED_IN]->(i:Item) 
RETURN i;
```